# Windows cmd redirect subcommand output to file

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, cuda, output-redirect

I am trying to debug an application using cuda-memcheck. What I want to do is to redirect output from my app to one file, but on the other hand, redirect stdout and stderr of the cuda-memcheck into another file. But I cannot get it working. This:

```
cuda-memcheck "app.exe > stdout1.txt" > memcheck.log 2>&1
```

does absolutely nothing. But if I delete the redirection inside the quotes (ignoring my app output), it executes. So the question is, how to redirect subcommand's stdout?

Comment: Have you tried the cmd option `--log-file` and/or `--save` of `cuda-memcheck`?

Comment: That redirects memcheck output, but not the output of the app it launches.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment on `cuda-memcheck`'s behavior, you could use the following command.

```
cuda-memcheck --log-file memcheck.log app.exe >app.stdout.txt
```

**Edit**

Here's my test on CentOS. It may work for Win32 console application but not for Win32 application.

a.cu

```
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    std::cout<< "hello world to stdout!" <<std::endl;
    std::cerr<< "hello world to stderr!" <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile command:

```
$ nvcc -O3 -o a a.cu
```

Run command:

```
$ cuda-memcheck --log-file mem.log a >a.stdout.log 2>a.stderr.log
```

Result files:

```
$ cat mem.log 
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors

$ cat a.stdout.log 
hello world to stdout!

$ cat a.stderr.log 
hello world to stderr!
```

Comment: still not working, the "app.stdout.txt" is empty after the debug

Comment: @Jofo Please see my test. Not sure why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Jofo It works on CentOS. You may need some change on Windows.

Comment: The problem of my app is that it does not normally print anything into a console (it is a Win32 application, not a console application). If I want to see the stdout, I need to redirect it into a file when the app is run. So     app.exe >>output.txt     works, but if I type just the app name into a console, I see nothing.

Comment: @Jofo Maybe you have to modify your app's code to print to some file by default. You don't need to use printf() in a Win32 application if there's no chance you can see the output in the console.

Comment: @Jofo Does `app.exe > stdout1.txt` work as expected (without memcheck)?